# Finding Standardized Text Pattern In String

Tags: python, regex, text-search

We are looking through a very large set of strings for standard number patterns in order to locate drawing sheet numbers.  For example valid sheet numbers are:   A-101, A101, C-101, C102, E-101, A1, C1, A-100-A, ect.

They may be contained in a string such as "The sheet number is A-101 first floor plan"

The sheet number patterns are always comprised of similar patterns of character type (numbers, characters and separators (-, space, _)) and if we convert all valid numbers to a pattern indicating the character type (A-101=ASNNN, A101=ANNN, A1 - AN, etc) that there are only ~100 valid patterns.

Our plan is to convert each character in the string to it's character type and then search for a valid pattern.  So the question is what is the best way to search through "AAASAAAAASAAAAAASAASASNNNSAAAAASAAAAASAAAA" to find one of 100 valid character type patterns.   We considered doing 100 text searches for each pattern, but there seems like there could be a better way to find a candidate pattern and then search to see if it is one of the 100 valid patterns.

Comment: Can you specify example input and expected output?

Comment: Do you have a complete list of patterns? If not, the problem may not be solvable.

Comment: Does lowercase letters never appear inside pattern? Are any other characters never present inside patterns but present in your documents? If yes consider removing them before begin of searching.

Comment: I have the top 100 patterns that find 99% of the values.  All characters are upper case.  Here are some examples of the text:

Comment: "A121C - FLOOR PLAN - SECTOR 3"

Comment: "A151B - FIRST FLOOR RCP - SECTORS 2 & 5" = "A151B"  ,  "58 A12-2A - Level 02 - Equipment Plan - Area A" = "A12-2A",  "[008] A1.0 - CONSTRUCTION FLOOR PLAN" = "A1.0", "MM19001 - E301 - FIRST FLOOR PLAN - LIGHTING = "E301"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

Is it what you want?

```py
import re

pattern_dict = {
    'S': r'[ _-]',
    'A': r'[A-Z]',
    'N': r'[0-9]',
}

patterns = [
    'ASNNN',
    'ANNN',
    'AN',
]

text = "A-1 A2 B-345 C678 D900 E80"

for pattern in patterns:
    converted = ''.join(pattern_dict[c] for c in pattern)
    print(pattern, re.findall(rf'\b{converted}\b', text))
```

output:

```
ASNNN ['B-345']
ANNN ['C678', 'D900']
AN ['A2']
```

---

#### Exmplanation

- `rf'some\b {string}'`: Combination of r-string and f-string.
- `r'some\b'`: Raw string. It prevents python string escaping. So it is same with `'some\\b'`
- `f'{string}'`: Literal format string. Python 3.6+ supports this syntax. It is similar to `'{}'.format(string)`.
- So you can alter `rf'\b{converted}\b'` to `'\\b' + converted + '\\b'`.
- `\b` in regex: It matches word boundary.

Comment: Really like the approach, can you explain the last line, what does `rf` and `\b` mean?

Comment: I appended explanations for that

Comment: Ah, the `rf` together tripped me up. Thanks for the explanation, learnt something new :)

Comment: That was not exactly what I was looking for.  However, with a couple of small changes it worked perfectly.  Also, I think your code would be a good approach for looking through a string with multiple patterns.   I will post my changes as a second answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    bookmark_strings = []
    bookmark_strings.append("I-111 - INTERIOR FINISH PLAN & FINISH SCHEDULE")
    bookmark_strings.append("M0.01   SCHEDULES & CALCULATIONS")
    bookmark_strings.append("M-1 HVAC PLAN - OH Maple Heights PERMIT")
    bookmark_strings.append("P-2 - PLUMBING DEMOLITION")

    pattern_dict = {
        'S': r'[. _-]',
        'A': r'[A-Z]',
        'N': r'[0-9]',
    }
    patterns = [
        'ASNNN',
        'ANSNN',
        'ASN',
        'ANNN'
    ]
    for bookmark in bookmark_strings:
        for pattern in patterns:
            converted = ''.join(pattern_dict[c] for c in pattern)
            if len(re.findall(rf'\b{converted}\b', bookmark)) > 0:
                print ("We found a match for pattern - {}, value = {} in bookmark {}".format(pattern, re.findall(rf'\b{converted}\b', bookmark) , bookmark))
```

Output:

```
We found a match for pattern - ASNNN, value = ['I-111'] in bookmark I-111 - INTERIOR FINISH PLAN & FINISH SCHEDULE
We found a match for pattern - ANSNN, value = ['M0.01'] in bookmark M0.01   SCHEDULES & CALCULATIONS
We found a match for pattern - ASN, value = ['M-1'] in bookmark M-1 HVAC PLAN - OH Maple Heights PERMIT
We found a match for pattern - ASN, value = ['P-2'] in bookmark P-2 - PLUMBING DEMOLITION
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex

```
import re

re.findall("[A-Z][-_ ]?[0-9]+",text)
```

Comment: Does not cover A101 and some other patterns mentioned by the OP.